# error: method drawOval in class Graphics cannot be applied to given types;? Not sure what this is about?

Tags: java, graphics

The error occurs on the `g.drawOval` line.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) 
{
     g.drawLine(150, 500, 150, 200);
     g.drawLine(01, 200, 644, 200);
     g.drawLine(430,200,430,500);
     g.drawLine(300,200,300,002);

     for ( int k = 0; k <= 100; k++)
     {
          int x = (int) (Math.random() * 200);
          int y = (int) (200 + Math.random() * 400);

          g.drawOval(x, y, 12.5, 12.5 );

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

That method accepts four integers as parameters. You are trying to pass two integers and two floats to it.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error because you are passing wrong type of parameters to the following method:

```
g.drawOval(x, y, 12.5, 12.5 );
```

Correct method signature is `drawOval(int, int, int, int)`

By passing `12.5` to the method you are passing `double` type to the method. So you can pass like this:

```
g.drawOval(x, y, 12, 12 );
```

Or

```
g.drawOval(x, y, 13, 13 );
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`drawOVal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawOval%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)  expects all 4 parameters of type `int` and you are giving it `double` type of paramters in the third and fourth arguments.

You must not provide `12.5` value, rather change it to some `int` value

like :

`g.drawOval(x, y, 12, 12 );`

Read the [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawOval%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) for more information